# MUI dropdown react application

Tags: material-ui

I am using MUI to develop my dashboard.

I am using MUI dropdown component to select the vendor details and there are two options for the Vendor dropdown. i.e "Surya Kumar Yadav", "Eswar". I used the same dropdown in all my cards. When I select the one of the dropdown in any card, it is reflected in all the other cards.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
  Button,
  CardActionArea,
  CardActions,
  Grid,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
} from "@mui/material";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { HttpClient } from "../http/http";

import { ConfirmDialog, confirmDialog } from "./ConfirmDialog";

const Services = () => {
  const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
  const [vendors, setVednors] = useState([]);
  const [selectedVendor, setSelectedVendor] = useState("");
  const PF =
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mern-stack-service-app.appspot.com/o/";
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  const init = () => fetchServices();

  const fetchServices = async () => {
    const services = await HttpClient.get(`services`);
    const vendors = await HttpClient.get(`vendor`);
    setVednors(vendors);
    setServices(services);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedVendor(event.target.value);
  };

  console.log(services);
  return services.length === 0 ? (
    <Grid>
      <Typography
        sx={{
          fontSize: 32,
          color: "blue",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          textDecoration: "underline",
        }}
      >
        Loading your services.....
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  ) : (
    <Grid container>
      <ConfirmDialog />
      <Grid container item xs={12} columnGap={2}>
        <Box sx={{ float: "right" }}>
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            onClick={() => {
              confirmDialog("Are you sure want to logout?", () => {
                localStorage.clear();
                navigate("/login");
              });
            }}
          >
            Logout
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={12} rowGap={2}>
        {services.map((service, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={index}>
            <Card>
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardContent>
                  <Grid
                    component="img"
                    sx={{
                      height: 150,
                      width: 350,
                      maxHeight: { xs: 150, md: 175 },
                      maxWidth: { xs: 350, md: 375 },
                      objectFit: "cover",
                    }}
                    alt="The house from the offer."
                    src={
                      PF +
                      service.photo +
                      "?alt=media&token=c19f2d0a-f254-4391-b589-ef7ee3cad9f5"
                    }
                  ></Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">
                      {service.service}
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 120 }} size="small" fullWidth>
                      <InputLabel id="demo-select-small">
                        Select Vendor
                      </InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        size="small"
                        labelId="demo-select-small"
                        id="demo-select-small"
                        value={selectedVendor}
                        label="Select Vendor"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      >
                        {vendors.map((vendor) => (
                          <MenuItem
                            key={vendor._id}
                            value={vendor.name}
                            id={vendor.name}
                          >
                            {vendor.name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
              <CardActions>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" fullWidth>
                    Book Service
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Services;
```

[image]

I want the dropdown action reflect in the selected card.

Answer (score 0):

It's because all of your mapped `Select` elements get their value from `selectedVendor`. you can change the code like this using these steps:

**First:**

Change the `selectingVendor` useState like this:

```
const [selectedVendors, setSelectedVendors] = useState([]);
```

**Second:**

And the `handleChange` function

```
const handleChange = (event,index) => {
    const currentSelectedVendors = [...selectedVendors];
    currentSelectedVendors[index] = event.target.value
    setSelectedVendors(currentSelectedVendors);
};
```

**Third:**

You need to change the `Select` Mui component props.

```
<Select
    size="small"
    labelId="demo-select-small"
    id="demo-select-small"
    value={selectedVendors[index] || ""}
    label="Select Vendor"
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,index)}
>
```

Although there is another solution for this problem and you can pull `<Select>`  logic out of `Services` component , I mean it's `selectingVendor` hook and it's change handler and create a new separate component which handles it.

*PS: I think it should be better to use `vendor._id` as the value prop of your `MenuItems`*

Comment: Nyce explanation, thank you.

Comment: If the answer is acceptable and useful for you, it is better to accept that by clicking on the check mark beside the answer box, to give a score to the answerer and help the other users to find better solution for their similar question more easily.